# NSAttributedString only works with Helvetica Neue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I'm trying to load a `UITextView` with an `NSAttributedString`. I'm loading the `NSAttributedString` from a Rich Text File "`.rtf`".

The Names of the files in my `[NSBundle mainBundle]` are `My Text-HelveticaNeue.rtf`, `My Text-TimesNewRomanPSMT.rtf`, and `My Text-MarkerFelt-Thin.rtf` These files each have the correct font set. They also have some text Bold.

Here's my code:

```
NSString *resourseName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"My Text-%@", self.currentFontName];
NSURL *rtfUrl = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:resourseName withExtension:@".rtf"];
NSError *error;

NSAttributedString *myAttributedTextString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithFileURL:rtfUrl options:nil documentAttributes:nil error:&error];

myTextView.attributedText = myAttributedTextString;

NSLog(@"%@", myAttributedTextString);
```

The Helvetica Neue file retains all formatting, including the text that is bold. But the other files only retain their font; they do not retain what text was bold. What could I be doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

I followed the suggestion of @Rob and here's the output I got.

```
Name:HelveticaNeue
Font:<UICTFont: 0xc1aab30> font-family: "Helvetica Neue"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 13.00pt
Bold:<UICTFont: 0xc1af770> font-family: "Helvetica Neue"; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; font-size: 13.00pt

Name:MarkerFelt-Thin
Font:<UICTFont: 0xfb16170> font-family: "MarkerFelt-Thin"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 13.00pt
Bold:<UICTFont: 0xfb18c60> font-family: "MarkerFelt-Thin"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 13.00pt

Name:TimesNewRomanPSMT
Font:<UICTFont: 0xc1cb730> font-family: "Times New Roman"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 13.00pt
Bold:<UICTFont: 0xc1c9b30> font-family: "Times New Roman"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 13.00pt
```

Comment: Did you add `My Text-MarkerFelt-Thin.rtf` and `Text-TimesNewRomanPSMT.rtf` in your project and in your plist ?

Comment: The problem isn't the text showing up. It's retaining the format. But, yes, I added the files to my project. How do I check to see if they are part of my plist? @JordanMontel

Comment: in your info.plist add key UIAppFonts (Fonts provided by application) and and the name of each custom font (for example : Text-TimesNewRomanPSMT.rtf)

Comment: They're all there. I only use Built in System Fonts. @JordanMontel

Answer (score 1):

iOS does not ship a bold or italic version of MarkerFelt-Thin, so you can't display that.

iOS does ship TimesNewRomanPS-BoldMT, but it does not seem to consider it to be the bold version of TimesNewRomanPSMT. (I haven't tested, but from your comment, I assume the same is true of TimesNewRomanPS-ItalicMT; it exists but is not considered the italic.) I would probably consider that a bug and open a radar.

A key point here is that you do not "bold" or "italic" a font. Bold fonts and italic fonts are complete fonts in their own right (individually designed by a font designer and packaged into their own font definition). They simply have a symbolic relationship to the base ("roman") version. If there is no bold version of a font installed, then asking for bold just returns the same font.

You can explore what fonts are available, and what font iOS considers the bold version of another font, using a program like this:

```
void LogFontNamed(NSString *name) {
  UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:name size:13];
  UIFontDescriptor *boldFontDescriptor = [[font fontDescriptor] fontDescriptorWithSymbolicTraits:UIFontDescriptorTraitBold];
  UIFont *boldFont = [UIFont fontWithDescriptor:boldFontDescriptor size:13];

  NSLog(@"=================");
  NSLog(@"Name:%@", name);
  NSLog(@"Font:%@", font);
  NSLog(@"Bold:%@", boldFont);
  NSLog(@"=================");
}

void printFonts() {
// uncomment if you want to explore the font lists
//  NSLog(@"%@",[UIFont familyNames]);
//  NSLog(@"%@", [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:@"Times New Roman"]);

  LogFontNamed(@"HelveticaNeue");
  LogFontNamed(@"MarkerFelt-Thin");
  LogFontNamed(@"TimesNewRomanPSMT");
  LogFontNamed(@"TimesNewRomanPS-BoldMT");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Very helpful. I've updated my question with the output. @Rob Napier

Comment: I was just recommending that you look at the output yourself to see what iOS is telling you. See how the bold version of MarkerFelt-Thin is MarkerFelt-Thin? That's what I mean; there is no bold of that font.